# Re-Assaigning a string variable to StringBuffer Object

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuffer

This is a block of code in one of my program. if i directly assign `sb1= str2` i am getting an error. so i am creating *two StringBuffer objects*.

Is there any possibility to achieve below requirement using only one StringBuffer Object.

```
   String str1, str2;
    Scanner scanObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    str1 = scanObj.next();
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer(str1);
    sb1.reverse();
    str1 = sb1.toString();
    char[] input1 = str1.toCharArray();
    str2 = scanObj.next();
    StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer(str2);
    sb2.reverse();
    str2 = sb2.toString();
    char[] input2 = str2.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Unless you need thread safety, you should use StringBuilder. It was introduced in Java 5 in 2004 and is preferred to StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
Scanner scanObj = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] input1 = new StringBuilder(scanObj.next()).reverse().toString().toCharArray();
char[] input2 = new StringBuilder(scanObj.next()).reverse().toString().toCharArray();
```

You can reuse a StringBuilder by using setLength(0) and append() but it would be more complex.

Comment: More complex how? Your approach could cause the memory to be re-allocated.

Comment: @Thom if you were worries about memory allocations you would just use a loop over a `char[]` and not have any StringBuilder. Given the program is not likely to worry about anything less than a micro-second, code simplicty is more likely to be important.

Answer (score 1):

use sb.setLength(0) and then add the new string back in. This should keep the same memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign `StringBuffer` directly to `String` because there are different objects. 
This should help you:

```
String yourStr = "some value";
StringBuffer buffer = new String(yourStr);
StringBuffer other = buffer;
```

You can put any `String` value into the `StringBuffer` object constructor.